# Density of linear span of idempotents in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

How do I show that the linear span of idempotents is dense in $L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mu)$ where $(\Omega,\mu)$ is a measure space? I don't really have any idea how to do this. Does it involve approximating some other class that is dense, say the simple functions?

Comment: The first thing is to identify the idempotents. The next thing is to note that the essential range of an $L^\infty$ function is (relatively) compact.

Comment: Why do I need compactness of the essential range?

Comment: The total boundedness is the important thing. You want, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, a finite set so that each value is within a distance of $\varepsilon$ from some point in the finite set.

Comment: @DanielFischer Am I right that $f\in L^\infty$ is idempotent if and only if $f=\chi_S$ (characteristic function) for $S\subseteq \Omega$ measurable?

Comment: @MattN. Yes. Modulo $a.e. [\mu]$, if we're pedantic.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! And: Yes, you're right (we are pedantic : ))

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you give me a hint on how to show that the simple functions are dense in $L^\infty$? What I have is that if $\varepsilon > 0$ then the goal is to find measurable sets $S_1,\dots, S_n$ and coefficients $c_1,\dots, c_n$ such that $$ \|f- \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \chi_{S_k}\|_\infty < \varepsilon$$

Now I'm not sure how to actually construct the sets and determine the coefficients.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I see that you already gave this hint in your very first comment to this question! Thank you : )

Comment: @DanielFischer But why is the image of an (essentially) bounded function compact? I can only see that it's bounded (obviously).

Comment: @MattN. The image of $f$ itself has no reason to be closed, nor actually bounded, if $\mu$ has infinite null sets. The _essential range_ ($\{ c : (\forall \rho>0)(\mu(f^{-1}(B_\rho(c))) > 0)\}$), however, is bounded and closed, so compact (but we don't need that it is closed; bounded, hence totally bounded [we're talking of subsets of euclidean space], is enough).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, "essential range", I see (new word added to my vocabulary!). And now I also understand the second half of your comment. I thought we use compactness to cover the range using finitely many $\varepsilon$-balls. Then the inverse image of each ball yields a measurable set $S_k$. Pick $c_k$ to be any value in $f(S_k)$. If we choose $\varepsilon$ small enough it will make the error small enough. But boundedness is of course enough to do that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you tell me if I got it? I posted a tentative proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/845802/).

Comment: @MattN. Answered [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16249983#16249983).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple functions are precisely the linear span of the idempotents.